# Unable to load ggplot2 package

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I was trying to install emmeans using install_github and it required that I install rtools and after attempting this I not only was unsuccessful in installing emmeans with the following code:

```
    devtools::install_github("rvlenth/emmeans", dependencies = TRUE, build_opts = "")
```

Received this:

```
Error: Failed to install 'emmeans' from GitHub: System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr: 
checking for file 'C:\Users\jmb827\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYrGInN\remotes387066d354e0\rvlenth-emmeans-32bf444/DESCRIPTION' ... OK 
preparing 'emmeans': 
checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK 
checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts 
checking for empty or unneeded directories 
looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added 
* building 'emmeans_1.4.5.009003.tar.gz' 

ERROR 
cannot change to directory ''
```

but now can not load `ggplot2` among other packages with error:

```
package �ggplot2� was built under R version 3.6.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 package ‘tibble’ does not have a namespace
```